# pydev syntax highlighting python builtins

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, pydev

Is there any way to make Eclipse/PyDev highlight the Python [built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html)?

For example, the Python IDLE highlights `int()` or `list()` but PyDev doesn't.

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.1 and PyDev 2.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently that's not really possible in PyDev. Please enter a feature request for that. See: http://pydev.org/about.html for details on where to report it...

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I've made a [search](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3268269&group_id=85796&atid=577332), and it have already been requested. Is there any way to vote on that request or something to make it have higher priority if more people want it?

Comment: I don't think you can vote in the SF tracker, but please add a comment saying 'I want this too' :)

Comment: This is definitely a useful feature because I just happened to use `list` as the first argument for a dictionary get, instead of `list_id` and since there was no syntax highlighting of built-ins, did not realize my bug until much later. Unable to add 'I want this too' to that feature request